# Multiplying string by a double

Tags: java, string, binary, double

I have code like this:

```
double priceMulti = 1.2;
    double price = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
  double date = 1980;
  double random = Math.random()*20;
  jLabel28.setText(priceMulti*String.valueOf(price)*date*random);
```

and in line with setting text I got an error "bad operand types for binary operator "*""
so I cant multiple anything.
Edit: main question is Solved, but now I want to use BigDecimal, not Doubles, because they are like 1.000012, and I dunno how.

Comment: Multiply all the values and then convert them to a String. `String.valueOf(priceMulti*price*date*random);`

Comment: Don't use floating-point for money. Use `BigDecimal.` You are entering a world of pain, wrong answers, books that don't balance, audit failures, rework ... Get it right the first time.

Comment: EJP, You are right. I Should use BigDecimal, because Doubles are like 1.12112312342134214, but I dont know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot multiply string by double in Java. You should do multiplication of all the doubles you have and then cast it to string to set the resulting value into Label text

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to multiply a `String` value with a `double` value. The arithmetic operators do not work on String values. You need to multiply all the doubles and then get the String value of it to set it to your `jLabel28`.

```
jLabel28.setText(String.valueOf(priceMulti * price * date * random));
```